# Mass convert videos to FLV format with watermarking in Windows

Tags: windows, conversion, flv, bulk

Is there a Windows program that can convert a bunch of videos and output in FLV format as well as include a watermark?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermarking FLV videos on Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/93504/watermarking-flv-videos-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this with recent ffmpeg is to use the overlay filter. The following command will place `watermark.png` on top of `input.flv`, with the upper-left corner of the watermark fifteen pixels to the right and ten pixels down from the upper-left corner of the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=15:10[outv]' -map [outv] -map 0:a \
-c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Obviously, change 15 or 10 to whatever values you want.

There are also a few constants you may find useful, if you're putting watermarks on multiple videos with separate resolutions:

- W and H are the width and height of the main video (`input.flv`)
- w and h are the width and height of the overlay video (`watermark.png`)

These can come in handy many times. For example, to place the watermark over the centre of the video, you could use:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]'
```

Similarly, to centre the watermark over the upper-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/6[outv]'
```

For the lower-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/(6/5)[outv]'
```

You can pretty much do whatever you need to.

See the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) documentation for more information.

Comment: Be cautious of copying your answers word for word from one question to the other.  In this case it's fine as the answers are the same.  Just be careful to not do it all the time :)

Comment: @KronoS yeah, I was careful to make sure it fitted, I have actually flagged a bunch of these questions as duplicates, but I decided to put the same answer on all of them, in case anyone needs a good answer in the time it takes for the mods to take a look at them (or the mods disagree with my flag). But thanks for the heads up, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script with Java using [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559691/ffmpeg-watermark-without-vhook

Another a very popular tool is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) so you can google for ffmpeg watermark and get a lot of ways of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that comes to mind is [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

For watermarking, it is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vhook 'vhook/imlib2.so -x 0 -y 0 -i overlay.png' output.avi
```

Where overlay.png is the watermark.

What you basically want to do is to put this in your workthrough and run it on every file in the project, and it should do the job.

Comment: -vhook is now an obsolete option.