# Watermarking videos on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, flv

I want to add watermarking on to my FLV videos. Previously I used to do that using FFmpeg's `vhook` option but due to some problems I had to upgrade it to the latest SVN revision. This version of FFmpeg doesn't have `vhook` support anymore.

I have tried mencoder with `bmovl` but mencoder seems to be pretty difficult to work with.

Is there any other feasible option of watermarking videos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this with recent ffmpeg is to use the overlay filter. The following command will place `watermark.png` on top of `input.flv`, with the upper-left corner of the watermark fifteen pixels to the right and ten pixels down from the upper-left corner of the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=15:10[outv]' -map [outv] -map 0:a \
-c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Obviously, change 15 or 10 to whatever values you want.

There are also a few constants you may find useful, if you're putting watermarks on multiple videos with separate resolutions:

- W and H are the width and height of the main video (`input.flv`)
- w and h are the width and height of the overlay video (`watermark.png`)

These can come in handy many times. For example, to place the watermark over the centre of the video, you could use:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]'
```

Similarly, to centre the watermark over the upper-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/6[outv]'
```

For the lower-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/(6/5)[outv]'
```

You can pretty much do whatever you need to.

See the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

VLC can watermark videos using the *Effects and Filters* > *Video Effects* > *Vout/Overlay* > *Add text*, and it can read FLV files. I've, personally, had varying success with encoding using VLC (or any program for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

i think vlc and mplayer and ffmpeg generally do good jobs. what problems are you having with mplayer/mencoder?

you could add the watermark on each frame using imagemagick or scripted gimp, but it will be very slow.

look: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_image